# infoWindow on MarkerClusterer in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need `infoWindow` to be opened instead of zooming in map, when clicking on the ClusterMarker.
I am using Gmaps util library `MarkerClusterer` for creating cluster of markers. I tried changing following line in markerclusterer.js

```
ClusterMarker_.prototype = new GOverlay();
```

with

```
ClusterMarker_.prototype = new GMarker();
```

so that I can get the `openInfoWindow()` function in the clustermarker, but that didnt worked out. Got some error. 
If possible, Please suggest solution so that this can be done with `MarkerClusterer`. Or else any other library which will be able to do this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off modifying the click event for the marker in markerclusterer.js starting on line 672.

Currently:

```
  GEvent.addDomListener(div, "click", function () {
    var pos = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(latlng);
    var sw = new GPoint(pos.x - padding, pos.y + padding);
    sw = map.fromDivPixelToLatLng(sw);
    var ne = new GPoint(pos.x + padding, pos.y - padding);
    ne = map.fromDivPixelToLatLng(ne);
    var zoom = map.getBoundsZoomLevel(new GLatLngBounds(sw, ne), map.getSize());
    map.setCenter(latlng, zoom);
  });
```

Change to something like:

```
  GEvent.addDomListener(div, "click", function () {
    map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng, "Put your infowindow content here");
  });
```

Obviously, depending on how much you want to abstract things, you could do a couple of things:

- Add configuration options to MarkerClusterer to specify whether to do zoom in functionality or infowindow functionality
- Define a callback function setup where you specify what function MarkerClusterer  will call when a cluster is clicked.

Comment: Because I didnt digged out properly in the API, I wasn't aware that i can open infoWindow using map object, thought only GMarker can do that. And was trying to make my ClusterNarker_ a GMarker. But that didnt worked out. Thanks for the redirection. Maybe this will work out. But I have to wait till monday to check out if it works.
Thanks again

Comment: The lastest version of markerclusterer (MarkerClustererPlus) lets you easily override some events like the click event. What i want to do is similar to the question, but i only want to open an infowindow with a list of some data from each marker in the cluster, ONLY for the last level of zoom. The one which is nearer to earth (i think its 21). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

For MarkerCluster v3 there is a custom event named '**clusterclick**', which return the markerCluster object, then you can get its center and assign it to an infoWindow, something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusterclick', function (mCluster) {
     //infowindow must be declared before in your code
     infowindow.setContent("your info");
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(mCluster.getCenter().ya, mCluster.getCenter().za);
     infowindow.setPosition(myLatlng);
     infowindow.open(map);
});
```

Also you have to set the zoomOnClick option on false:

```
var mcoptions = { zoomOnClick: false, showText: true, averageCenter: true}
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersArray, mcoptions);
```

Comment: you also have to set the zoomOnClick option on false I updated my answer

Comment: there seems to be some variable definitions missing. I appreciate the response, but a more workable solution would be great.