# JS Function undefined when it is clearly a prototype of the object I am using

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using GoogleMaps JS API V3 with ClusterMarker. So far so good, I have a working map with customised clusters.

I decided I needed a method to open the infoWindow with some information of the clicked cluster, including some anchored links.

I did some searching on SO and Google and came up with something along these lines from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4337808/1010632).

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function (clickedCluster) {


    console.log(clickedCluster);

    var center = clickedCluster.getCenter();

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(center);

    // infowindow.setContent("Info Window");
    // infowindow.setPosition(latLng);
    // infowindow.open(map);

});
```

In the `console.log(clickedCluster)` I'm given a Cluster object that has 6 methods, and a load of properties. One of these functions is `getCenter()` that returns the 'Center of the cluster icon that has been clicked'.

When I uncomment this line: `var center = clickedCluster.getCenter();` I get an error saying that getCenter() is not a function.

Can anyone help me shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to the problem turned out to be that `clickedCluster` was returned as an array. The below works great.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function (clickedCluster) {

    var center = clickedCluster[0].getCenter();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(),center.lng());

    infoWindow.setContent(getDailyDeals(center.lat(),center.lng()));
    infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
});
```